# Run IPython notebook with Spark in another directory

Tags: jupyter-notebook, apache-spark

I am trying to use IPython Notebook with spark.

When I am in the spark installation directory, this command works well:

```
IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook --pylab inline" ./bin/pyspark
```

However, I can create notebooks only on the spark installation directory and its sub directories. 
If I launch this command on another directory on my computer:

```
PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --pylab inline" /Users/poiuytrez/Documents/programs/spark/bin/pyspark
```

I get only a regular pyspark shell and not a notebook. Do you have any ideas of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might have left off the initial `I` in `IPYTHON_OPTS` in your second command?